# Python - is there a way to identify the directionality of angles?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image, angle

in the image below, a so-called teardrop-like DNA molecule is shown. For me, the distribution of the bending angles of this DNA is of very high interest. In red, a trace yielded by `skimage.morphology.skeletonize` is shown.
In my program, the trace is being represented as a numpy-array: Each entry in the numpy-array is a float64 tuple corresponding to the x and y coordinate of the trace point in the image. So if I apply `np.diff(trace, axis=0)`, I get the segments I want to analyze in vector from.

**The problem:** Now, I now how to calculate an angle between two subsequent segments. However, I do not now if the angle is oriented clockwise or counter-clockwise. For example, at one point, the DNA bends to the left, so the angle there would be different from the one measured when to DNA bends to the right, which it mostly does. What would be a way to fix this?

**My idea so far:**
I thought of interpolating each segment and then checking if the next segment lies below or above the interpolated line, indicating a clockwise vs. counter-clockwise angle. But this seems hard to implement, and since I am a beginner, any input would be highly appreciated! [image: The Teardrop Molecule. I want to measure the angles between subsequent segments of the trace in red.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cross product `np.cross` will help you here. For a simple triangle going around first counter-clockwise, then clockwise this could look like this (can be optimized, left it longer for clarity). The angle output is the angle enclosed between the vector with the directions following the right-hand rule: EDIT: added a curve with direction change, added graph (annotations for going counter-clockwise):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path

def drangl(vsgi, vsgi1):
    '''sin(theta)=|axb|/(|a||b|)'''
    return np.arcsin(np.cross(vsgi, vsgi1)/np.linalg.norm(vsgi)/np.linalg.norm(vsgi1))

print('going around the traingle counter-clockwise and clockwise:\n')

trace = np.array([(0.,0.), (10.,-1.), (5.,10.), (0.,0.)])
vsegs = np.diff(trace, axis=0)

for iv in [0,1,-1]: # counter-clockwise
    print(f'ctr-cl: {iv:d} {drangl(vsegs[iv], vsegs[iv+1]):2.2f}')
for iv in [-1,1,0]: # clockwise
    print(f'cw: {iv:d} {drangl(vsegs[iv], vsegs[iv+1]):2.2f}')
    
print('\nnow with direction change in the path:\n')

trace = np.array([(0.,0.), (10.,-1.), (9., 5.), (12., 5.), (5.,10.), (0.,0.)])
vsegs = np.diff(trace, axis=0)
    
for iv in [0,1,2,3,-1]: # counter-clockwise
    print(f'ctr-cl: {iv:d} {drangl(vsegs[iv], vsegs[iv+1]):2.2f}')
for iv in [-1,3,2,1,0]: # clockwise
    print(f'cw: {iv:d} {drangl(vsegs[iv], vsegs[iv+1]):2.2f}')
    
codes = [
    Path.MOVETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.CLOSEPOLY,
]

path = Path(trace, codes)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='white', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 13)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 11)
ax.annotate('turns right', xy=(9, 5), xytext=(5, 5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )
ax.annotate('turns left', xy=(12, 5), xytext=(10, 10),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )
plt.show()
```

which produces

going around the traingle counter-clockwise and clockwise:

```
ctr-cl: 0 1.04
ctr-cl: 1 0.89
ctr-cl: -1 1.21
cw: -1 1.21
cw: 1 0.89
cw: 0 1.04

now with direction change in the path:

ctr-cl: 0 1.31
ctr-cl: 1 -1.41
ctr-cl: 2 0.62
ctr-cl: 3 1.41
ctr-cl: -1 1.21
cw: -1 1.21
cw: 3 1.41
cw: 2 0.62
cw: 1 -1.41
cw: 0 1.31
```

[image]

The sign change now indicates where the curve changes direction.

Comment: Why do you calculate ```np.arcsin``` and not ```np.arccos```?

Comment: I use |axb|=|a| |b| sin(theta) where theta is the enclosing angle between a and b, but I guess the direction of the resulting vector is what is important to your problem.

Comment: One question: Why exactly does that yield a negative sign?

Comment: As far as I know, the formula you use works with magnitudes of vectors, so I don't see where the sign comes into play

Comment: the sign would come into play if you cross two vectors to take one step (imagine a triangle of vector addition: you go along two sides to come to the resulting vector). Adding is commutative, but the "handedness" of going left or right you would be able to identify via cross product, it would switch signs (as in the example above: the absolute angle values are the same, but the signs are inverted). Maybe check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, but thanks so far. My problem is that I still can't see if my DNA suddently turns towards the left. Let's say all the segments up to a certain point line up clockwise. Then, suddenly, the next segment turns counter-clockwise. But I still don't see how the program would check that now it needs to calculate the complementary angle.

Comment: Ah yes: as long as you go around right, the cross product of seg(i-1) and seg(i) would always have the same sign. If it switches sign it would be an indicator that the last segment turned left. The problem with the angles is that they are not base 2*pi but, as you rightfully commented, directed.

Comment: and one last q: are the values in your output in rad, I assume?

Comment: yes it is. I think its default for most trig functions. Good luck, you'll make it work, its an interesting problem. If you get stuck post some of the data in your question.